# How to create integration test for file upload in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

What is the best way for testing file uploads for Rails Applications? I'm currently using [Paperclip](http://www.thoughtbot.com/projects/paperclip) for uploads, but I guess that doesn't make much difference.

**Should I even create tests for file upload, or is it better to just stub it all out and don't create any *real upload tests*?**

Say I have some tests just for the upload. **Should I also cover cropping in my tests?**

**What would be the best way to test image cropping?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cucumber with Webrat gives you the step of:

```
When I attach the file at "spec/fixtures/fugu.png" to "file"
```

which you can use in features. For more information about [the official Cucumber site is very helpful](http://cukes.info/).

Secondly, to test for the cropping you could code a custom step for this:

```
Then /^the image "(.*?)" should be (\d+)x(\d+)$/ do |id, width, height|
  image = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body).css("##{id}")
  image["width"].should eql(width)
  image["height"].should eql(height)
end
```